# How can I specify an @CollectionTable relationship between multiple tables in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor

I have a project written in SpringBoot 2 and a MySQL database and I'm trying to rewrite it to Spring WebFlux using MongoDB.

There are 2 tables: **CONTRACT** and **CONTRACT_CONTRACTOR**.
And the fact is that in the class **Contract** there is a relationship with the second table

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CONTRACT_CONTRACTOR", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONTRACT_ID"))
    @Column(name = "CONTRACTOR_NUMBER")
    private List<String> contractorsNumbers;
```

Those. it turns out that in the table **CONTRACT** there is a link to the table **CONTRACT_CONTRACTOR**.

And I can’t figure out how to do this with MongoDB.
Can someone give a clever idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use mongodb's projections and aggregations. With `ReactiveMongoTemplate` you can use them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you explain to me more, please?